# distribution theory $\ \ \text{order}(T) = \max(\text{order}(T')-1,0)\ $?

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

I would like to know in what case is it possible that $\text{order}(T) = \text{order}(T') \ge 1$. So I came to write this :

- $\|\varphi\| = \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |\varphi(x)|$
- Let $T \in D'(\mathbb{R})$ be a distribution compactly supported on $\Omega$ and $\text{order}(T') = k \ge 1$, that is $$\forall \varphi \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}),\qquad |\langle T', \varphi \rangle| \le C\sum_{m \le k} \|\partial_m \varphi\|$$

Then pick $\phi \in C^\infty_c([a,b])$ with $[a,b]$ slightly larger than $\Omega$ and  $\phi(x) = 1$ for $x \in \Omega$, and let  $\displaystyle I[\varphi](x) = \phi(x) \int_a^x \varphi(t)dt$.

Since $\partial_m I[\varphi] = \sum_{l=0}^m {m \choose l} (\partial_{m-l}\phi)(\partial_l \int \varphi) = (\partial_m \phi)(\int \varphi)+\sum_{l=1}^m {m \choose l} (\partial_{m-l}\phi)(\partial_{l-1} \varphi)$ we have

$\begin{eqnarray} \|\partial_m I[\varphi]\| &\le& \|(\partial_m \phi)({\textstyle\int} \varphi)\|+\sum_{l=1}^m {m \choose l} \|(\partial_{m-l}\phi)(\partial_{l-1} \varphi)\| \\
&\le& \|\partial_m \phi\|\, |b-a|\,\| \varphi\|+\sum_{l=1}^m {m \choose l} \|\partial_{m-l}\phi\|\|\partial_{l-1} \varphi\| \\
&\le & C_2\sum_{l\, \le\, \max(0,m-1)} \|\partial_{l-1} \varphi\|\end{eqnarray}$

And hence
$$|\langle T, \varphi \rangle| = |\langle T', I[\varphi] \rangle|  \le 
C\sum_{m \le k} \|\partial_m I[\varphi]\|
\le C_3\sum_{l\, \le\, \color{red}{k-1}} \|\partial_m  \varphi \|$$

whence $\text{order}(T) \le k-1$

**Is it correct ?**

Comment: Your test function $I[\varphi]$ is not compactly supported in $\Omega$, so the inequality $|\langle T', I[\varphi] \rangle| \le C\sum_{m \le k} \|\partial_m I[ \varphi]\|_{\infty, \Omega}$ looks cheesy.

Comment: My remark was about that subscript $\Omega$ (in $|\langle T', I[\varphi] \rangle| \le C\sum_{m \le k} \|\partial_m I[ \varphi]\|_{\infty, \Omega}$). As you have just shown, it should have been $[a,b]$, with $[a,b]$ containing the support of $\phi$.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy So you agree that at least when $T$ is compactly supported, then $order(T) = order(T')-1$ ? And when $T$ isn't, we can reduce it to a compactly supported distribution for some given set of test functions, so it should stay true ?

Comment: I don't really see where you use the fact that $T$ is compactly supported.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy at $-\langle T',\phi \int \varphi \rangle = \langle T,\phi' \int \varphi + \phi \varphi \rangle = \langle T,  \varphi \rangle$ if $\phi = 1$ on $support(T) $

Comment: @TZakrevskiy in other words, $\int \varphi$ isn't compactly supported in general, so I need to restrict to a compact support and multiply it by $\phi$

Comment: Erm, how about the very trivial "if a test function $\psi$ is zero on the support of a distribution $T$, then it is not guaranteed that $\langle T,\psi\rangle =0$"?

Comment: @TZakrevskiy sry I don't see what you mean, and to me $support(\delta') = (-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ so $\psi = 0$ on $support(T) \implies \langle T, \psi \rangle$

Comment: In your example $supp(\delta')=\{0\}$, take a test function $\psi$ such that $\psi(x)=x$ for $|x|<1$. While $\psi(0)=0$, you have $\langle \delta',\psi\rangle\ne0$.