# Schwarz distribution as a derivative of a continuous function

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

Every distribution $t\in\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ of **compact support** is of the form

$$
 t(x) = \sum_{|\alpha|<m}\partial^\alpha t_\alpha(x),
$$
where $\alpha$ is multi-index, $m$ - some constant and $t_\alpha \in C(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

It is not true that every distribution $t\in\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is of the above form (the sum may be infinite).

However, I suppose that every **Schwarz distribution** $t\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is of the above form, i.e.
$$
 t(x) = \sum_{|\alpha|<m}\partial^\alpha t_\alpha(x),
$$
where $\alpha$ is multi-index, $m$ - some constant and $t_\alpha \in C(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Am I right? Can you provide a reference.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1963159/distribution-theory-textordert-max-textordert-1-0 it is the same as saying every distribution with compact support has finite order

Comment: All tempered distributions are of finite order, hence you hypothesis is true.