# Which Fourier series define a (tempered) distribution?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series, distribution-theory

Let ${\sum}_{-\infty}^{+\infty} a_k e^{ikx}$ be the Fourier series of a function. 
Which condition must be satisfied by the coefficients ${a_k}$ so that the series defines a distribution in $\mathcal{D'}$ or in $\mathcal{S'}$?

I know that a series of functions that define a distribution in $\mathcal{D'}$ is a distribution in the same space if it converges uniformly on compact sets; a series of functions that define a distribution in $\mathcal{S'}$ is itself a tempered distribution if it converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$. How does this all apply to the Fourier series?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The necessary and sufficient condition is that there exists $n$ such that $|a_k|=O(|k|^n)$; that is, the coefficients are of at most polynomial growth. This applies to both $\mathcal D'$ and $\mathcal S'$ equally, since for periodic distributions the "tempered" property brings no additional restriction: they do not grow at infinity anyway.

**Sufficiency**: if $|a_k|=O(|k|^n)$, let $b_k = a_k/(ik)^{n+2}$ for $k\ne0 $ (and let's say $b_0=0$). Then $\sum b_k e^{ikx}$ converges uniformly, so it defines a continuous periodic function $f$ (hence a tempered distribution). Since the derivative is a continuous operation with respect to distributional convergence, any convergent series of distributions can be differentiated term by term. Doing this $(n+2)$ times, we get the original Fourier series (up to a constant). Its sum is $f^{(n+2)}$, understood as a distributional derivative.

**Necessity**: Every distribution is of finite order on a compact set, hence can be expressed by differentiating a continuous  function a bunch of times (mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2059814), for example). The Fourier series of a continuous function has bounded coefficients. Translating this to the derivatives, we get a polynomial  bound on the Fourier coefficients.